# Matlab: How do I save an output to a file and overwrite old values when using importdata?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm using importdata to strip off a header and import a file into my workspace.

The file contains rotation matrices plus translation vectors.
In my matlab script I transform the rotation matrices into quaternions.
In my output file I would like to have quaternions plus translation vectors, i.e. I want to replace the old values from the rotation matrix with the new values for the quaternions.

However, I am only able to output the quaternions to the command window, but don't know how to replace the values.

Here is my code:

```
path = '\filepath';
[head DELIM NHEADERLINES] = importdata([path],' ',9);
Rotation = head.data(:,1:9); 
Translation = head.data(:,10:12); 
RotationMatrix= zeros([3 3 size(Rotation,1)]);

for i=1:size(Rotation,1)
RotationMatrix(:,:,i) = [Rotation(i,1:3); Rotation(i,4:6); Rotation(i,7:9)];
end

Quaternion = SpinCalc('DCMtoQ',RotationMatrix,0.1,0);
```

How can I get the quaternion into the original file and overwrite the rotation matrix?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `dlmread` and `dlmwrite` is more recommended in your case.

```
    M = dlmread(filename,' ',9,0); % start from row 10, column 1
    Rotation = M(:,1:9);
    Translation = M(:,10:12);
    .
    .
    .
    dlmwrite(Quaternion,'delimiter',' ','newline','pc');
```

If you prefer to modify the original file instead of replacing it, use the following

```
    fileID = fopen(filename,'r+'); % with read and write permission
    fseek(fileID, pos, 'bof'); % where pos is the starting position of the bytes you want to read
    M = fscanf(fileID, repmat('%g ',1,12), nlines); % read 12 columns of numbers for at most n lines.
    .
    .
    .
    fseek(fileID, pos, 'bof'); % go back to the position
    fprintf(fileID, repmat('%g ',1,12), Quaternion);
```

This is just a suggestion. The above codes may not run as desired, so I recommend you to read the documentation for more info. Cheers.